# FB PHP authentication

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I found this code here http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

```
<?php 

   $app_id = "YOUR_APP_ID";
   $app_secret = "YOUR_APP_SECRET";
   $my_url = "YOUR_URL";

   session_start();
   $code = $_REQUEST["code"];

   if(empty($code)) {
     $_SESSION['state'] = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE)); //CSRF protection
     $dialog_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
       . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url) . "&state="
       . $_SESSION['state'];

     echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
   }

   if($_REQUEST['state'] == $_SESSION['state']) {
     $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
       . "client_id=" . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
       . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret . "&code=" . $code;

     $response = file_get_contents($token_url);
     $params = null;
     parse_str($response, $params);

     $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" 
       . $params[‘access_token’];

     $user = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url));
     echo("Hello " . $user->name);
   }
   else {
     echo("The state does not match. You may be a victim of CSRF.");
   }

?>
```

What I changed was the app id app secret and URL, I created a page with one HTML sentence  I uploaded this on Web server and I get error page not found.  Can anyone help me with that?  Also do I need to include anything?

Comment: What "not found"? If your script is not found - then probably you're requesting the wrong url. And the question has nothing to do with facebook.

Comment: The script is found after I click on hyperlink in the page I see the url in browser changes too and it has facebook.com and some token ... but then it displays page not found

Comment: "but then it displays page not found" --- **what page**??? Can you give us the url of that page?

Comment: thats what I wrote ... first a link comes up on my first page, the code for which is given above after I click on the link .... it changes to facebook.com/some long token ...... if you are asking for the actual url I am sorry I cant provide that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do in your code is kind of a workaround for something that already exists. Please use the [Facebook PHP SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk) for things that you're trying right now. It makes the thing a lot easier and you probably get to your goal in less time.

Comment: Hi could you please give me some guideline on how to use it or point to some tutorial that has some info because all the tutorials I saw on web seemed to be outdated

Comment: Would you please click on the link I embedded on "Facebook PHP SDK". The SDK's last change is about 1 day old and if you scroll down right after clicking the link you can see the usage. If you need more information you should consider learning php first!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the facebook SDK.
Here is the sample tutorial, which works me fine,

http://www.9lessons.info/2011/01/facebook-graph-api-connect-with-php-and.html

I am sure it will fix your issue.

Comment: there is no such thing as on success page in the current fb application registration

Answer (score 1):

You should use the Facebook PHP SDK ([see on github](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk)). It is dead simple to deal with logging users in. Here is how it looks like :

```
require 'facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(...);

$user = $facebook->getUser();
```

If the user is logged in, `$user` will contain his Facebook ID. But it does not mean that you have a valid access token to make API calls : if he just logged out from Facebook, `$user` will not be null but the access token will not be valid anymore.

One way to check if you have a valid token is actually to try to make a API call :

```
if ($user) {
  // The user is logged in
  try {
    $facebook->api('/me');
    // Here : API call succeeded, you have a valid access token
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    // Here : API call failed, you don't have a valid access token
    // you have to send him to $facebook->getLoginUrl()
    $user = null;
  }
} else {
  // The user is not logged
  // you have to send him to $facebook->getLoginUrl()
}
```

And then, to log in the user or to get a valid access token :

```
if (!$user) {
  // display link to $facebook->getLoginUrl();
}
```

You may want to check [the example of the Facebook PHP SDK](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php) to have the complete flow, it is well documented.

Hope that helps.